# Qual a classificação gramatical e o significado de "não" em "o que ela não diria se soubesse que já fui um presidiário"

Tags: significado, classificação-de-palavras

O Priberam classifica **"não"** como advérbio ou substantivo masculino.  O léxico online não cita a classificação gramatical. Por outro lado, além de não conseguir classificar, não consigo perceber o **"não"** como negação nessa frase:

> O que ela não diria se soubesse que já fui um presidiário

Parece mesmo querer dizer o contrário: "O que ela diria?"

Comment: Uma questão muito mais interessante do que poderá parecer à primeira vista. O que um **não** não consegue fazer numa frase!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na frase

> O que ela **não** diria se soubesse que já fui um presidiário

a palavra **não**, gramaticalmente, é um advérbio que qualifica *diria*. Quanto ao significado, o **não** introduz um elemento retórico: o ex-presidiário insinua que ela diria coisas muito negativas se soubesse do seu passado. O efeito retórico é reforçado se a frase terminar com ponto final ou de exclamação em vez de interrogação. Já a frase

> O que diria ela se soubesse que já fui um presidiário?

indica apenas curiosidade genuína em saber o que ela diria: diria ela, "Seu cafajeste..." ou "Seu tolinho, porque não me contou? Estava com medo da minha reação..." Um elemento retórico poderia também ser conseguido na frase original tirando o **não** e introduzindo uma entoação apropriada, que se consegue reproduzir na escrita apenas imperfeitamente:

> *O que ela diria* se soubesse que já fui um presidiário.